# Is there something like a Web driver, but for android apps?

Tags: c#, webdriver

Is it possible to control Android Apps with an other app, like it is possible to control a browser with a webdriver? If yes, is it compatible with c#?

Comment: from your question it is not clear what do you want to achieve. Are you looking for an app capable of running android apps in it? e.g. Android emulator?

Comment: Anything is possible with enough resources and time. This question is far too broad. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I asked whether there is a way to make an app (in c#) to control other apps. For example to send messages automated. If it is possible I like to know how. In the best case a solution that is simular to a web-driver, but for an app, not a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question you are asking for something like [Appium](https://appium.io/) which is "an open source **test automation framework** for use with native, hybrid and **mobile web apps**.
It drives iOS, **Android**, and Windows apps using the **WebDriver** protocol."

And Yes, you can code with **C#**. Here you have a [link with an example of it](http://executeautomation.com/blog/writing-simple-code-using-appium-with-c/)

I hope this might help you.